# Thread is not working. the application close unexpexted.

Tags: android

i am trying to show the progress dialog in my program when press the refresh button but the application close unexpexted with error in debugger that the thread which one is created ui hierachy can only touch it.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.refreshView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void refreshView(){
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Bitmap bm = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        try 
        {
            URLConnection conn = new URL("http://technomoot.edu.pk/$Common/Image/Content/ciit_logo.jpg").openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 8192);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (bis != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    bis.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (is != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    is.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);
}

    public void onRefresh(View view) {

        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading","Loading the image of the Day");
        Thread th = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                refreshView();
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                        );
            }

        };th.start();   
    }

}
```

Comment: the picture url is just temorary. the origional picture from url load well and work ok but on pressign refresh it shows waiting or process screen but app died after few second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate with `UI` from worker `Thread`! It's prohibited! If you want to update `UI` just use

- **`runOnUiThread()`**
- **`AsyncTask`**

So try it like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
      // do your work.

   }
});
```

`AsyncTask` is more complex, also generic-type that provides some benefits like type control etc. You can look at example here:

- [**`Android application (performance and more) analysis tools -
  Tutorial`**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Comment: where you actually creating new `Thread` just place there `runOnUiThread()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a ui operation from a non ui thread, you can Use `runOnUiThread`..
or better use `AsynchTask`

```
public YourTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Object,Object>{ //change Object to required type
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Context context;

public YourTask(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

protected void onPreExecute(Object o){
     dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading","Loading the image of the Day");
}

protected void doInBackground(Object o){
    refreshView();
}

protected void onPostExecute(Object o){
    img.setImageBitmap(bm);
    dialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: i am new and dont know how to do this. i am found this and use handler that i dont know how to use. andi am still cant understan what is meant by non ui thread. can any one please fix this code in a very easy way so i can understand it.